# How to add OnClickListener in recyclerView according to the item position

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

## RecyclerView Code:[`OnClickListener`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6bqA.png)

```
package com.example.cardview;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class ArrayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArrayAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private String[] divisionName;
ArrayAdapter(String[] phoneNumebr) {
    this.divisionName = phoneNumebr;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
    View v = inflater.inflate( R.layout.element, parent, false );
    return new ViewHolder( v );
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.cNumbers.setText(divisionName[position] );
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(this,divisionName[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } );

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return divisionName.length;
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView cNumbers;

    ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super( itemView );
        this.cNumbers = itemView.findViewById( R.id.cNumbers );
    }
```

How to add OnClickListener in recyclerView according to the item position

Comment: Your code is right so what's your issue.

Comment: In Toast.makeText(this,divisionName[position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  divisionNmae[position] generate error.

Comment: can you post your log/error

Comment: Inside Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext... instead this

Answer (score 0):

> How to add OnClickListener in recyclerView according to the item
> position

To add OnClickListener to `RecyclerView` items, you achieve that within your custom `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` class, by setting .`onClickListener()` to the View passed into the ViewHolder constructor

snippet from your code:

```
static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView cNumbers;

    ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super( itemView );
        this.cNumbers = itemView.findViewById( R.id.cNumbers );
        
        listItem.setOnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Click on position number: " + getAdapterPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), divisionName[getAdapterPosition()],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Change Your Toast.

```
        Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(),"You clicked "+divisionName[position],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```